# SQL limit несколько условий

Tags: php, sql

коллеги помоги правильно написать запрос 
столкнулся с проблемой что нужно вывести определенно количество записей с определенным параметром 
к примеру

```
id name cat  time
1  aa    0   2019-03-21
2  ad    0   2019-02-21
3  dd    1   2019-03-18
4  dd    2   2019-03-21
5  as    1   2019-01-02
```

и таких записей может быть много 
как мне выбрать по 50 последних записей по каждой категории cat ?

лимит не знаю как можно тут использовать 
нашел решение с UNION 
но не уверен что ето правильное решение к примеру

```
SELECT * FROM table where cat=0  ORDER BY time DESC  limit 50
UNION 
SELECT * FROM table where cat=1  ORDER BY time DESC  limit 50
```

так как с результатирующей таблицы мне еще нужно выполнить определенные операции

Comment: Простого способа нет. Если нужно делать операции, то тогда юнион. Но я не вижу в этом особого смысла. проще выбрать все в пхп и там уже делать операции

Comment: Укажите точно СУБД, включая версию.

Comment: *не уверен что ето правильное решение* Если список категорий статический (не изменяется со временем) - это вполне правильное решение.

Comment: MySql  версии не знаю на локальном нет смысла смотреть так как на проде она может отличаться

Comment: *MySql версии не знаю* Ну так узнайте. Решение для версии 5+ и для версии 8+ будут различаться самым радикальным образом. Заодно - сколько всего записей в таблице? хотя бы порядок...

Comment: – Akina   MySql  5 версия

Comment: И ещё вопрос - решение в формате не запроса, а хранимой процедуры - устроит? С точки зрения выполнения из PHP никакой разницы нет. А сэкономить ресурсов можно изрядно...

Comment: – Akina не совсем понял вопрос , мне нужно выбрать данные запросом а дальше уже работать с выбранными данными (сгруппировать , вычесть , посчитать )

Comment: довольно странная идея - группировать сучайным образом выбранные записи. если бы группиорвка была хотя бы осмысленной - за определенную дату например - это можно было бы понять. а взятые с потолка 50 записей?

Comment: @Ипатьев Почему с потолка-то? товарищ пишет *50 **последних** записей*, т.е. явно имеет в виду сортировку по дате.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT `table`.*,
              IF(@cat=`table`.cat, 
                 @rownum:=@rownum+1, 
                 @rownum:=1+LEAST(0,@cat:=`table`.cat)) rown 
       FROM `table`, 
            (SELECT @rownum:=1, @cat:='_') q1
       ORDER BY cat, time DESC
     ) q2
WHERE rown <= 50
ORDER BY cat, time DESC
```

Если количество записей в каждой группе значительно (на порядки) больше 50, разумнее реализовать это в формате хранимой процедуры. Курсор по cat, копирование по 50 записей для каждого значения во временную таблицу, и затем select из неё в выходной поток.

Comment: выводит 821 результат а по плану 3 группы по  50 записей должно быть 150 записей

Comment: Ну так проверьте результат, и сообщите ТИП отклонения. Если в таблице всего 3 различных значения cat, то среди 821 записи должны быть либо дубликаты по (cat, rown), либо записи с rown > 50.

Comment: – Akina спасибо ваше решение работает правильно